# SQL date format being interpreted diff on diff machines

Tags: sql, date

User1 and User2 are connecting to the SQL Server `Moon\SQL2k8R2` (`Valuations` database). Both are executing the same queries, passing date as an `nvarchar` in the below listed format. Earlier the user1 was passing `YYYY-dd-MM` and now gets an error message

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

```
User    Earlier             Now
User1   YYYY-dd-MM ‘2012-18-05’ YYYY-MM-dd ‘2012-05-18’
User2   Never tried     YYYY-dd-MM ‘2012-18-05’
```

User 1 tells us that nothing has changed on their machine.

I have validated the keyboard, language and regional settings on both User 1 and User 2 settings and they both have UK (dd/mm/YYYY - 18/05/2012) settings.

I am trying to explain the possible reason for change in this behavior, any inputs appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466100/conversion-of-a-varchar-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-out-of

Comment: So are we saying that the issue is at the logged in user? The sql service runs under my account and so does the app both are set to british english.

Comment: I have tried this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173907 and the result I get is, British, British English and dmy